# Select two numbers between 1 to 100

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Question: In how many ways we can select two numbers between $1$ and $100$ so that the two selected numbers have a difference of at most $10$.

My Approach:
I calculated the answer to be $925$ but I am not really sure if it is the correct answer.

This how I approached it, As the question says "between" so it means numbers ranging from $2$ to $99$, so 
$(2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6),\dots,(2,12)$ so $10$ ways like this
proceeding similarly till $(89,99)$ we will get $880$ numbers. From here onwards, $(90,99)$—$9$ ways; $(91,99)$ &mdash $8$ ways; … $(98,99)$ — $1$ way, so $45$ ways like this.
Adding up all: $880+45 = 925$ ways in all

Can someone please help me with this question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What help do you need?  You have solved it correctly.  I might have recognized the triangular number at the top end more quickly than you express in your post, but that is the only simplification that I see.

Comment: I am not really sure about the answer, hence I wanted to ask the community if it is right or wrong, if it is wrong then how to proceed correctly.

Comment: Between $1$ and $100$ is more likely to be intended as including the endpoints.

Comment: I agree with Andre' Nicolas. However, if the problem does exclude the endpoints, then you have a nice solution. Well done! :)

Comment: Is "between 1 to 100" the exact wording of the question? The normal English expression is "between 1 **and** 100".

Answer (score 1):

90*10+10C2=945

explanation: let the smaller number is chosen from  1 to 90 any number. if the chosen number is n then another number can be any number from (n+1) to (n+10). the number of pair is 90*10 if the smaller number belongs to 1 from 90. then if if the samller number is greater than 90 then number of pair is 10C2=45